# delimit a newline string to comma separated in javascript

Tags: javascript, servicenow

Hi I have a set of string values like

```
12345

12346

12347

12348

12342

12345

12334
```

The values will be received from a list, one below another
I need to assign these values to a string with comma separated, like:

```
12345,12346,12347,12348...
```

in javascript. I am getting these values as input parameters from a multi-line text box.

Comment: Do you have some code?

Answer (score 5):

Using split with a regEx, can be a bit more robust than just splitting on `\n` (newline).

eg.

```js
var data = "1234\n5678    1235 \n8884";

console.log(data.split(/\s+/).join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

If text is:

```
12346
12347
12348
12342
12345
```

First split string from multy line text box to one array:

```
var numbers = myText.split("\n");
```

After that just join list to string

```
   // If you want to sort:
   var sortedNumbers = numbers.sort()
   // then join with comma:
   var result = sortedNumbers.join(',');
```

Result will be:

```
12342,12345,12346,12347,12348
```